# Fix error code P2122 for Mustang 2014 with engine 3.7L

Tags: ford, mustang

Knowledge level: I know little about cars

Help needed: Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix the error code P2122 for Ford Mustang car 2014 with engine 3.7L

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search displayed [this](https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/Discussion-c23850_ds739397) result. I'm assuming that's you as well? If not, small world!

The answer provided on that site (shown below) seems to cover it, but I would also check the fuses related to the Throttle Position Sensor (TPS) which should be on the Powertrain Control Module (PCM) itself. I would then make sure there is continuity in the wiring, and use a multi meter to see if the TPS is sending the correct voltage. If you cannot read a voltage from the TPS, replacing the entire assembly as the answer below suggests is probably your best bet.

Answer from linked site:

> Basically you need to replace the gas peddle. It is simple to do. The one on my 2011 Chevy Impala cost $75....... P2122 FORD - Throttle/Pedal Position Sensor/Switch 'D' Circuit Low - Possible causes - Faulty Accelerator Pedal Position (APP) Sensor - Accelerator Pedal Position (APP) Sensor harness is open or shorted - Accelerator Pedal Position (APP) Sensor circuit poor electrical connection - Faulty Powertrain Control Module (PCM) - Possible symptoms - Engine Light ON (or Service Engine Soon Warning Light) - No throttle pedal response P2122 Ford Description The Accelerator Pedal Position (APP) sensor is an input to the Powertrain Control Module (PCM) and used to determine the amount of torque requested by the operator. There are 2 pedal position signals in the sensor. Both signals, APP and APP2, have a positive slope (increasing angle, increasing voltage), but are offset and increase at different rates. The 2 pedal position signals make sure the PCM receives a correct input even if 1 signal has a concern. The PCM determines if a signal is incorrect by calculating where it should be, inferred from the other signals. If a concern is present with one of the circuits the other input is used. There are 2 reference voltage circuits, 2 signal return circuits, and 2 signal circuits (a total of 6 circuits and pins) between the PCM and the APP sensor assembly. The pedal position signal is converted to pedal travel degrees (rotary angle) by the PCM. The software converts these degrees to counts, which is the input to the torque based strategy. The P2122 code sets when The accelerator pedal position (APP) sensor 1 is out of self-test range low.